# Custom Django FileField url widget won't upload any file in admin change_form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I have a `Files` table with information about uploaded files in a remote directory. This is the model for that table:

```
class Files(models.Model):    
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subjectid = models.ForeignKey('Subjects', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='subjectid')
    filetypeid = models.ForeignKey(FileTypes, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='filetypeid')
    filedescid = models.ForeignKey(FileDescription, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='filedescid')      
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)       
    filename = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments/', blank=True, null=True)            
    ispublic = models.IntegerField(choices=YESNO)
    extra_info = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename.name or ''

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'files'
        verbose_name_plural = 'files'
```

I've created my own URL widget to replace the Django FileField url shown as '**Currently:**' in the `change_form` template. The link points to a view that downloads the file. So far, so good it works but the problem is that when I try to add a new file I can select the new file with the `Browse` file button but when I click on `Save` the field `filename` field is empty and no file is uploaded.

```
class MyAdminURLFieldWidget(URLInput):
    template_name = 'admin/widgets/url.html'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        #final_attrs = {'class': 'vURLField'}
        final_attrs = {'type': 'file'}
        if attrs is not None:
            final_attrs.update(attrs)

        super(MyAdminURLFieldWidget, self).__init__(attrs=final_attrs)



    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super(MyAdminURLFieldWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context['current_label'] = _('Currently:')
        context['change_label'] = _('Change:')        
        context['widget']['href'] = smart_urlquote('/DownloadView/' + str(value.instance.id) + '/attachment/') if value else ''
        return context


class FilesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', '_animalid', '_filename', '_filedesc', 'ispublic', 'extra_info')
    search_fields = ('subjectid__animalid','filename')
    list_per_page = 50

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):                                
        if db_field.name == 'filename':
            request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
            kwargs['widget'] = MyAdminURLFieldWidget

            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)                                 

        else:
            return super(FilesAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)


    def _animalid(self, obj):
        return obj.subjectid.animalid

    def _filename(self, obj):
        return obj.filename.name

    def _filedesc(self, obj):
        return obj.filedescid.description
```

Can anybody tell what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Hi lost Django community,

I will answer my own question since it seems that nobody was able to realize the answer. It happens that as newbie I'm following examples I've found here and there but there is little about sub-classing the `FileField` associated widget. So, after diving deep into the Django code I've found the answer. In my case the problem was I derived my `MyAdminURLFieldWidget` from `URLInput` instead of the correct subclass `ClearableFileInput`.

You are welcome.